# How to fix the "Video is not the main content of the page" error for text contents

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

I have several pages with textual content (about 1500-200 words with photos) on my site, which rank high on Google in their keywords. We produced a video suitable for this content for each page that we want to place next to the text on these pages; so that the user can see both the text and the video.

Since about a month ago, when it seems that Google's algorithm has been updated, for all my videos, the error "**Video is not the main content of the page**" was displayed in the search console in the no video indexed mode.

Interestingly, pages with videos were also removed from the google text results! It means that we are not in the first 10 pages for the keywords that we ranked one or two on the first page!

In search console, the status of that page is indexed, but not the video. However, the page does not appear in text results or video results.

The page inspect status is like below:
[image: The page inspect status for "Video is not the main content of the page" error]

**There is no video schema on this page**. I don't want this page to come as a video result. The same normal result is enough. In fact, the video is not the main content of the page, and that's why we don't have a video schema!

The videos were uploaded directly to our site. (self-hosted) and displayed with html5 player.

We **only have the article schema** for the pages. (As before, it was ranked. Now only a self-hosted video has been added to the page.)

Is there a way to solve this problem? Can I make Google understand that there is no need to index these pages as video result and that the same page as before in the results is enough for me?

Any idea or solution?
Thanks :)

---

### update 1:

In the search console inspect, All these pages are available to google and reported as **indexed**.

### Update 2:

I removed videos from some of these pages and after one day (or several hours) the pages come back into the regular results. (in it's keywords)

Answer (score 3):

Google made an update last spring (2023) that made it so that video thumbnails would only show up next to search results when the main content of the page *is* the video.

In your situation, which is very common one, you include the video is as a supplementary resource to the content.

As seen below, from then on results that previously were shown with video thumbnails, but weren't video results, will see those thumbnails removed.

[image: graphic depicting that search results with video thumbnails will no longer contain them when the video is not the main content of the page on Google]

Essentially, you don't have to do anything to tell Google that the page shouldn't be indexed as a video result. Google's crawling systems will detect this automatically.

You can safely ignore this annotation in Search Console (it's not an error), because based on what you've said, it sounds like you don't want it to show up as a video result in the first place.

Now to address the issue of the pages disappearing from results

If the pages are listed as "indexed" in Google Search Console, `Performance Report -> Pages` and check the queries, impressions and average position.

If the pages are receiving impressions, it is likely that these things aren't related. You could have lost your ranking for another reason.

There have been a number of updates recently, but the primary one was the [Helpful Content](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/helpful-content-system) Update.

Here are some additional resources to help you diagnose this.

[SEMrush Sensor](https://www.semrush.com/sensor/)
[Panguin Tool](https://www.barracuda.digital/panguin-tool)

---

**Additional:** This past December, Google issued an [update](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2023/12/video-is-the-main-content) around this announcing that when you're in video mode (make a search, and click the "videos" tab), results will only include videos where the video is the main content of the page.

Comment: My problem is that this page has been completely removed from the results (both the normal results and the video tab) and has lost its rank in all the results.Although the only change was the addition of this video and I did not have any other changes for such pages.

Comment: I'll modify my answer today, I missed that part. In the meantime can you go to search console -> URL Inspection, and test the live URL?

Comment: Thanks. The URL live test is ok. Page availability, Video discovery, and also Breadcrumbs and Sitelinks searchbox have green check.

Comment: Does it say the page is indexed?

Comment: Yes! but when we search the page keyword (that had rank a few days ago) the page is not on the first 10 pages (100 results) at all! :( (+ also all images included in these pages)

Comment: I just updated the question. (update 1 and 2)

Comment: That's nuts! Can you upload a screenshot of the SERP for any of them or a screenshot in search console? That sounds like a bug to me.